# Shim function in static library

Tags: linux, linker, shim

I have an opaque statically linked library (`.a` file) and some opaque object files (`.o`) that call functions in said static library. I would like to add wrappers around some function calls in the static library.

If it were a dynamic library, I would use `LD_PRELOAD` at runtime, but since this is statically linked, I'm sure I will have to use a compile-time technique. I was thinking `-Z muldefs`, which would allow me to override the function calls, but I still need to be able to call the original function within my shim, so I can't use that directly.

So far, the best solution I can come up with is to use `objcopy --redefine-sym` to rename the functions within the opaque library, then make my shim code call the functions by their new name. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way?

No, that's the best you can do.